# How to run multiple Bazel Query operations in parallel?

Tags: bazel

I have to perform a few queries for analyzing a set of targets. I tried running them multi-threaded but Bazel still seems to execute them only serially.

I know Bazel in general [does not allow parallel execution of work](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/532). But I was wondering if there is a way to make query work assuming there is no modification/build happening meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

You could use separate [--output_base](https://bazel.build/docs/user-manual#output-base)s, although that will extract all the external repositories multiple times.

Depending on your queries, you may be able to use [genquery](https://bazel.build/reference/be/general#genquery) to get the results via a `bazel build` command. However, the lack of support for wildcards is often problematic.

Much of the work `bazel query` does is cached. If you do a big enough query first (even if you discard the results), it should load everything in parallel and then the subsequent ones should be fast.